How to import data into PieCloudDB faster
I'm using python to write data from pandas dataframe to my PieCloudDB database, but the import using the following method is particularly slow:
def insert_rows(rows:pd.DataFrame,table="t_weather_history", conn=None, target_fields=None, commit_every=10000,
                replace=False):
    if len(rows.index) > 0:
            current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        if conn is None:
            engine = get_sqlalchemy_engine()
            rows.to_sql(table, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, method='multi')
        else:
            rows.to_sql(table, con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False, method='multi')
            duration = (datetime.datetime.now() - current_time).total_seconds()
        print("ToSql insert {} rows into Table take {} seconds".format(len(rows),duration))

There are a total of 250,000 records. Is there a better way to improve the import efficiency?

to_sql is implemented using insert into, which has poor import efficiency. You can use copy to import into PieCloudDB. Adjusting your method to the following code:
def insert_rows_copy(rows:pd.DataFrame,table="t_weather_history",conn=None, target_fields=None, commit_every=10000,
                replace=False):
    if len(rows.index) > 0:
            current_time=datetime.datetime.now()
        bytes_data_io = io.BytesIO()
        rows.to_csv(bytes_data_io, sep='\t', index=False,header=False)
        bytes_data_io.seek(0)
        if conn is None:
            conn = get_sqlalchemy_engine()
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.copy_from(bytes_data_io,table)
            conn.commit()
        else:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.copy_from( bytes_data_io,table)
            conn.commit()
        duration = (datetime.datetime.now() - current_time).total_seconds()
        print("ToCsv copy {} rows into Table take {} seconds".format(len(rows),duration))

